# Do I have to explicitly free memory when using vlfeat?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, vlfeat, gmm

I'm using VLFeat to train a Gaussian Mixture Model(GMM), and I'm not sure if I should manually free memory when the following commands are used:

```
float *means = (float *) vl_gmm_get_means(gmm);
float *covariances = (float *) vl_gmm_get_covariances(gmm);
float *priors = (float *) vl_gmm_get_priors(gmm);
```

Do I have to manually write codes like the following?

```
free(means);
free(covariances);
free(priors);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you mean by "let Visual Studio do its job'...

If memory is allocated, it needs to be freed.  C++ is not a garbage collected language so all memory allocation/deallocation is explicit through new/delete (or malloc/free).

I have never used the library (VLFeat) in question, but I googled its memory allocation functions.  My guess, is that you should use `vl_free()` to free memory returned by the library.  The implementation may just wrap `free()` or some other function, but usually for libs like this, you should use lib functions to manage memory returned from the lib.

The documentation for `vl_free()` states: This function frees a memory block allocated by vl_malloc, vl_calloc, or vl_realloc. The synopsis is the same as the POSIX malloc function.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure how the function  `vl_gmm_get_means(gmm);` was implemented, since it was a build-in function and source code is not avaliable... Still I could try to `vl_free` anything for safety though...